# How to tidy up the layout so that it aligns - Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, bootstrap-4, layout

So, I want to put fellow gate A side by side, I use bootstrap

Like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psh54.jpg)

This Code :

```
  <section class="content float-top float-right"> 
<h2>Gate A</h2>
<div class="card ml-1" style="width: 35rem">
  <div class="row ml-3 mt-3 mb-3 mr-3">

    <?php
      foreach ($tamu as $tamu_item) : 
    ?>

    <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
      <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><?php echo $tamu_item->gateA ?></button>
      </div>   
    </div>
   <?php endforeach;?>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [bootstrap's grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/)

Each gate will be inside a column like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <section class="content float-top float-right">
                <h2>Gate A</h2>
            </section>
            <!-- other elements -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <section class="content float-top float-right">
                <h2>Gate B</h2>
            </section>
             <!-- other elements -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```